# MPMusicPlayerController skips to next song after continuing playback

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am using the `MPMusicPlayerController` to play songs from Apple Music. I am periodically (every several seconds) changing the song queue using

`setQueue(with: MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: ids))`

I don't have any problems during music playback, the song queue is updated as requested, I can skip to next song and everything is fine. However, whenever I **pause** the player in the middle of the song, wait a bit till a new queue is set, and play again - the current song is lost and next song starts to play!

So imagine the following situation:

1. I have songs `A, B, C, D`
2. I set it as a song queue and call `play()`
3. `player.nowPlayingItem` returns `A`
4. I set the song queue to `E, F, G, H` while playing
5. I call `player.skipToNext()` - song `E` starts playing, as expected
6. I call `player.pause()` - song `E` pauses
7. I call `player.play()` - song `E` continues to play. **Everything is fine till now**
8. I call `player.pause()` again - song `E` pauses
9. I set the song queue to `I, J, K, L`.
10. I call `player.play()` - **I expect the paused song `E` to continue playing. Instead, song `I` starts playing**

I also did some log output for the above scenario:

```
func togglePlayPause() {
    if player.playbackState == .playing {
        player.pause()
    } else {
        NSLog("NP before \(player.nowPlayingItem)") // prints E at step 10
        player.play()
        NSLog("NP after \(player.nowPlayingItem)") // prints nil at step 10
    }
}
```

Strangely, pause/play from lock screen works fine, even if I change the queue in between.

Has anyone experienced similar problem, any hints/workarounds how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I used

```
player.currentPlaybackRate = 1
```

instead of `player.play()`. Seems like `play()` does a bit more than just playing from paused location.